# Communication between a server thread and a man-machine interface (MMI)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, network-programming

I need your advice on a program I'm coding right now. Let me first present you what it is.

### Design

I'm designing a man-machine interface (MMI). In this MMI, there are two core elements:

- The `MainWindow`:

  [image: MainWindow MMI]

This MainWindow is the base of everything. *Important*: Here, I launch in a thread a `server` that receives the data from a client. This data is very important to the next element.

- Supervision

  [image: Supervision IHM]

This window contains a `QTableWidget`, the goal is to show in pseudo-real time the data received on the server in the thread of MainWindow.

### The Problem

The server in the thread owned by the `MainWindow` receive a structure every 10 mS. How can I send these data to the `Supervision` window if it's open? I was thinking of using shared memory, but not really sure about this, and doesn't really which method I have to use.

### Some Solutions

I tried to implement the solution of Sebastian Lange :

- An emit in the thread Server
- A connect in the MainWindow
- A slot in supervision

So now my thread `Server` emit a signal at every frame received. But how can I do the connect in the MainWindow and how will `Supervision` receive the `struct emit` in the signal?

Here's the code of my emit:

```
MainWindow* MainWindow::m_psMainWindow = nullptr; // C++ 11 nullptr
void MainWindow::emit_signal_TrameRecu(StructureSupervision::T_StructureSupervision* ptr){
    emit signal_TrameRecu(ptr);
}

void MainWindow::lancerServeur(std::atomic<bool>& boolServer){
    serveur s;
    StructureSupervision::T_StructureSupervision* bufferStructureRecu;
    while(boolServer){
        bufferStructureRecu = s.receiveDataUDP();
        if(bufferStructureRecu->SystemData._statutGroundFlight != 0){
           m_psMainWindow->emit_signal_TrameRecu( bufferStructureRecu );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create signals (holding your data, best one signal for each datatype) and use ```emit```. In Supervision-window create slots that take these datatypes as parameter and ```connect``` them. Read on http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: @SebastianLange If I emit a signal in MainWindow, Supervision will be able to receive it ?

Comment: If Supervision knows about the mainwindow it will. Better would be to have public slots defined in supervision window class and have the connects in mainwindow. The emit will be in serverthread, which mainwindow does know about also. you can then connect in mainwindow, from serverthread signal to supervision public slot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Queued Connections

Qt makes cross thread communication easy when you use *queued connections*.

Your calls to `connect` should use the [`Qt::QueuedConnection`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) or [`Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) connection types.

### Custom Types in Slots and Signals

To use custom types (structs) in slots, signals, QVariant and properties you need to *declare* and *register* the type to make it available to the Qt dynamic type system.

In your header (.hpp) use [`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) and in your source (.cpp) use [`qRegisterMetaType`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType).

### Worked Example

**server.hpp**

```
#ifndef SERVER_HPP
#define SERVER_HPP
#include <QtCore>

struct customdata
{
  int id;
  QDateTime tstamp;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(customdata)

class Server : public QThread
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Server();
  signals:
    void sendData(const customdata& d);
  protected:
    virtual void run();
};

#endif
```

**server.cpp**

```
#include "server.hpp"

static const int customdata_metatype_id =
  qRegisterMetaType<customdata>();

Server::Server() : QThread() {}

void Server::run()
{
  customdata d;
  d.id = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    d.id++;
    d.tstamp = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    emit sendData(d);

    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

**window.hpp**

```
#ifndef WINDOW_HPP
#define WINDOW_HPP
#include <QtGui>
#include "server.hpp"

class Window : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Window();
  public slots:
    void receiveData(const customdata& d);
  private:
    QListWidget* mList;
};

#endif
```

**window.cpp**

```
#include "window.hpp"

Window::Window() : QWidget(),mList(new QListWidget())
{
  resize(400, 300);
  QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
  mainLayout->addWidget(mList);
  setLayout(mainLayout);
}

void Window::receiveData(const customdata& d)
{
  QString str(QString("%1 %2").arg(d.id).arg(d.tstamp.toString()));
  mList->addItem(str);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>

#include "server.hpp"
#include "window.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  Window win;
  Server ser;

  QObject::connect(
    &ser, SIGNAL(sendData(customdata)),
    &win, SLOT(receiveData(customdata)),
    Qt::QueuedConnection);

  win.show();
  ser.start();

  return app.exec();
}
```

**test.pro**

```
TEMPLATE=app
QT=core gui
HEADERS=server.hpp window.hpp
SOURCES=main.cpp server.cpp window.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

I once (in the days of Qt 3.2) implemented this cross thread communication using `QApplication::postEvent` (now [QCoreApplication::postEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent)). However nowadays best practise is to use promises and futures to communicate asynchronously between threads. Promises and futures has become a part of recent C++ standard and the concepts are also implemented separately as part of Qt 5 Concurrent framework. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html