# Emit a signal in a static function

Tags: c++, qt, signals, emit

I've got a a static function : `static void lancerServeur(std::atomic<bool>& boolServer)` , this function is force to be static because I launch it in a thread, but due to this, I can't emit a signal in this function. Here's what I try to do :

```
void MainWindow::lancerServeur(std::atomic<bool>& boolServer){
    serveur s;
    StructureSupervision::T_StructureSupervision* bufferStructureRecu;
    while(boolServer){
        bufferStructureRecu = s.receiveDataUDP();
        if(bufferStructureRecu->SystemData._statutGroundFlight != 0){
            emit this->signal_TrameRecu(bufferStructureRecu);//IMPOSSIBLE TO DO
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to emit my signal ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm very much afraid that you're running in circles, layering progressively more complex and convoluted solutions for what is a single problem. To start with, a networked application in Qt should be designed to work *fine* with *no* thread use. The moving of a `QObject` to a thread is the last step after things otherwise work, and is done to reduce the latency. Thread-safe methods don't need to be static. They just need to be either thread-safe or slots, and then you can *safely* invoke the slots from a `QObject` that resides in a thread (via `invokeMethod` or via signal-slot connection).

Comment: Perhaps you should post a question asking for a canonical solution to whatever your basic problem is. Such a question might attract a complete, canonical, that's-how-one-should-start type of an answer. To make the question on-topic, you should describe what you've tried, and the problems you've faced.

Comment: Hey @KubaOber Well I start by using your method, but after 3 days of research, I can't find the problem, so I must go on and change, so I have to use winsocks ... I agree with you, it can become more complex, but I have result to show, like you know I'm a trainee, and I don't have lots of consideration from my hierarchy, so if I don't move on, I'm fired. Anyway, I've got a proper result that works now, maybe not the best, but it works.

Comment: I want to thank you for your help, the static is a bit weird, but it won't compile if the method is not static, don't know why :/ , maybe it's because I call it somewhere, but it's in the same class, so there's no problem normally. I post a canocical question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446043/communication-between-server-thread-and-ihm But I have a satisfying result now, but you can propose something better ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep a static pointer to the instance of MainWindow in the MainWindow class and initialise it in the constructor. Then you can use that pointer to call the emit from the static function.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    ...
    private:
        static MainWindow* m_psMainWindow;

        void emit_signal_TrameRecu(StructureSupervision::T_StructureSupervision* ptr)
        {
            emit signal_TrameRecup(ptr);
        }
};

// Implementation

// init static ptr
MainWindow* MainWindow::m_psMainWindow = nullptr; // C++ 11 nullptr

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    m_psMainWindow = this;
}


void MainWindow::lancerServeur(std::atomic<bool>& boolServer)
{
    StructureSupervision::T_StructureSupervision* bufferStructureRecu;

    ...

    if(m_psMainWindow)
        m_psMainWindow->emit_signal_TrameRecu( bufferStructureRecu );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass the pointer to the class as a parameter to lancerServeur, or you can use a slot on a worker class and move it to a thread.

See this example http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html on how to use a slot to do the work on a separate thread.